# select an item with a null comparison

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm not using a full on DB Abstraction library, and am using raw sql templates in psycopg2 that look like this :

```
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE message = %(message)s ;
```

The ideal query to retrieve my intended results looks something like this :

```
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE message = 'a3cbb207' ;
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE message IS NULL ;
```

Unfortunately... the obvious problem is that my NULL comparisons come out looking like this:

```
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE message = NULL ;
```

... which is not the correct comparison - and doesn't give me the intended result set.

My actual queries are much more complex than the illustration above - so I can't change them easily.  ( which would be the correct solution , i agree.  i'm looking for an emergency fix right now )

Does anyone know of a workaround , so I can keep the same singular templates going until a proper fix is in place ?  I was trying to get `coalesce` and/or `cast` to work , but I struck out with my attempts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE message IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'the text';

SELECT id FROM table WHERE message IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL;
```

`NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL` is `true`, not `NULL`, so it's like `=` but with different `NULL` comparison semantics. Great in trigger functions.

AFAIK can't use `IS DISTINCT FROM` for index lookups though, so be careful there. It can be better to use separate tests for null and value.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the edit. I usually remember. Really wish the Pg docs had a "current" in the version selector, not just explicit versions, as it'd be easier to make sure to get the right link.

Comment: I edited to fix a little "reverse logic bug" in the answer.  :-)

Comment: @kgrittn Thanks. Would you believe I never noticed `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` and have been writing `NOT (a IS DISTINCT FROM b)` all this time? *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks! This is a perfect drop-in solution!

Comment: This answer deserves a `+1` for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `NULL` does not actually equal anything (not even another `NULL`) as the value of `NULL` is intended to represent an *unknown*.  Your best bet is to change your templates to handle this correctly.

If it's possible that you can pass in separate values for the left and right operand in your template, one way to still use an equal sign would be:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE true = (message is null);
```

Comment: thanks , tested it out, but another tip to use 'is not distinct form' worked better.

template changes will happen in the future.  i just needed to fix something that was in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing your query clause as follows:

```
WHERE message = %(message)s OR ((%message)s IS NULL AND message IS NULL))
```

It's a bit rough, but it means "select the message that match my parameter, or all the messages that are null if my parameter is null". It should do the trick.

Comment: thanks , tested it out, but another tip to use 'is not distinct form' worked better.