# Selecting rows with a specific column as null gives column does not exist error

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I'm using psycopg2, and the query is a simple string.

```
Q= "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE PUBLISH_TIME IS NULL"
```

When I execute it in `pgAdmin`, it gives me the correct results, but throws

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "publish_time" does not exist
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014902/select-an-item-with-a-null-comparison)
but it's still the same error output.

Comment: What are the column names for POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this answer here in case anyone has the same problem. This cannot be done via psycopg2 due to a design feature. I added a flag to my model which depended on publish_date column, created a db script that wrote this flag and went ahead with

```
Q= "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE PUBLISH_FLAG = False;"
```